# To add values to a django model while I add value to another model

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model 'Books' and another model 'Products'. When I add a Book from django admin, I want the Book name and Book Code to be added to the Model 'Products'.

Comment: Create a foreign key and establish a relationship, try some of the code and ask a question

Answer (score 2):

Edited thanks to  Waqar Ali, I forgot to add `if self.pk is None:` condition.

In the save method of the Book Class, I would create an instance of Product using the Book attributes like below :

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ref

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.pk is None: 
            product = Product(ref = self.code, name = self.title)
            product.save()
```

Try to show some of your code next time, it will be easier to help.

Comment: won't it create a new product every time book.save() is called ?

Comment: Thanks I have just updated it. Forgot to add the condition. However I do think that the other answer is the more appropriate: the foreign key

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  Foreign Key and access it using Foreign key

```
    class Books(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
       

    class Products(models.Model):
        book = models.ForeignKey(
            Books,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
     
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def book_name(self):
            return self.book.name
        def book_code(self):
            return self.book.code
```